# Using conditions for both collections (original and foreign) in lookup $match

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if it is a real problem or just lack of documentations.
You can put conditions for documents in foreign collection in a lookup `$match`.
You can also put conditions for the documents of original collection in a lookup `$match` with `$expr`.

But when I want to use both of those features, it doesn't work. This is sample lookup in aggregation

```
  { $lookup:
    {
      from: 'books',
      localField: 'itemId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      let: { "itemType": "$itemType" },
      pipeline: [
         { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] } }}
      ],
      as: 'bookData'
    }
  }
```

`$expr` is putting condition for original documents. But what if I want to get only foreign documents with `status: 'OK'` ? Something like:

```
{ $match: { status: "OK", $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] } }}
```

Does not work.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Can you try wrapping these two conditions in an `$and` operator?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus sorry that was my mistake. It doesn't give error. Just not working. I tried with $and, still the same. What is happening is that seems like after adding `status: "OK"` to `$match`, `$expr` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: So your `$expr` condition if just ignored if `$match` object contains other query conditions? Can you past example documents and expected output of this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to play with the situation you provided.
Try to put `$expr` as the first key of `$match` object. And it should do the thing.

```
   { $lookup:
    {
      from: 'books',
      localField: 'itemId',
      foreignField: '_id',
      let: { "itemType": "$itemType" },
      pipeline: [
         { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] }, status: 'OK' }}
      ],
      as: 'bookData'
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's strange but actually worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer is "wrong" in the sense that it doesn't actually change anything. The ordering that the fields for the `$match` predicate are expressed in does not make a difference. I would demonstrate this with your specific situation, but there is an extra complication there which we will get to in a moment. In the meantime, consider the following document:

```
  {
    _id: 1,
    status: "OK",
    key: 123
  }
```

This query:

```
db.collection.find({
  status: "OK",
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$key",
      123
    ]
  }
})
```

And this query, which just has the order of the predicates reversed:

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      "$key",
      123
    ]
  },
  status: "OK"
})
```

Will both find and return that document. A playground demonstration of the first can be found [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ss1HwuZntM-) and the second one is [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pbr90J5oGvj).

Similarly, your original `$match`:

```
{ $match: { status: "OK", $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] } }}
```

Will behave the same as the one in the accepted answer:

```
{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] }, status: 'OK' }}
```

Said another way, there is no difference in behavior based on whether or not the `$expr` is used first. However, I suspect the overall aggregation is not expressing your desired logic. Let's explore that a little further. First, we need to address this:

> $expr is putting condition for original documents.

This is not really true. According to [the documentation for `$expr`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), that operator "*allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language.*"

A primary use of this functionality, and indeed the first one listed in the documentation, is to [compare two fields from a single document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/#compare-two-fields-from-a-single-document). In the context of `$lookup`, this ability to refer to fields from the original documents allows you to compare their values against the collection that you are joining with. The documentation has some examples of that, such as [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-multiple-joins-and-a-correlated-subquery-with--lookup) and other places on that page which refer to `$expr`.

With that in mind, let's come back to your aggregation. If I am understanding correctly, your intent with the  `{ $expr: { $eq: ["$$itemType", "book"] }` predicate is to filter documents from the *original* collection. Is that right?

If so, then that is not what your aggregation is currently doing. You can see in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2tlmemx2glw) that the `$match` nested inside of the `$lookup` `pipeline` does *not* affect the documents from the original collection. Instead, you should do that filtering via an initial `$match` on the base `pipeline`. So something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nCnY-B1kgND):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          "$itemType",
          "book"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Or, more simply, [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0qEbB9cIqT2):

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "itemType": "book"
    }
  }
])
```

Based on all of this, your final pipeline should probably look similar to the following:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "itemType": "book"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "books",
      localField: "itemId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      let: {
        "itemType": "$itemType"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: "OK"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "bookData"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eOt7R3OabZM). This pipeline:

1. Filters the data in the original collection (`orders`) by their `itemType`. From the sample data, it removes the document with `_id: 3` as it has a different `itemType` than the one we are looking for (`"book"`).
2. It uses the `localField`/`foreignField` syntax to find data in `books` where the `_id` of the `books` document matches the `itemId` of the source document(s) in the `orders` collection.
3. It further uses the `let`/`pipeline` syntax to express the additional condition that the `status` of the `books` document is `"OK"`. This is why `books` document with the `status` of `"BAD"` does not get pulled into the `bookData` for the `orders` document with `_id: 2`.

Documentation for the (combined) second and third parts is [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#perform-a-concise-correlated-subquery-with--lookup).